# How to Add a badge to UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, badge

In my app I need to add count at left top to `UIButton` like `UIButtonItem`. How it is possible and how to add `MIBadgeButton` to my project.

Answer (score 3):

For adding a badge count to UIBUtton you need to add the custom view as a subview to UIButton, there is no direct way.
For adding MIBadgeButton to the project:
2 Ways:

1. Add through a CocoaPods as mentioned in the link https://github.com/mustafaibrahim989/MIBadgeButton
2. Add as Submodule -> Download project from Github. Copy the MIBadgeButton and MIBadgeLabel files then add them to your project. Refer to their example project for a clear understanding

Comment: Its Working Thank You

Comment: Okay. please accept the answer, so that if anybody is searching this type of question they will make use of it.

Comment: Good Suggestion...@YogeshMv

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by defining a subclass of UIButton, including a function to add and another to remove the badge.

```
class ButtonWithBadge: UIButton {

required init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

func addBadge(withBadgeTag tag: Int, badgeSize size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 7, height: 7), indentTop: CGFloat = 3, indentRight: CGFloat = 3) {
    let badge: UILabel = {
        let bdg = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        bdg.tag = tag
        bdg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bdg.layer.cornerRadius = bdg.bounds.size.height / 2
        bdg.layer.masksToBounds = true
        bdg.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        return bdg
    }()
    self.addSubview(badge)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        badge.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant:  -indentRight),
        badge.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: indentTop),
        badge.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width),
        badge.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
        ])
}

func removeBadge(withBadgeTag tag: Int) {
    if let badge = self.viewWithTag(tag) {
            badge.removeFromSuperview()
        }
}
```

}

The optional parameters of the function "addBadge" allow to define the size of the badge and the position relative to the topAnchor and rightAnchor of the button in cases where the defaults are not appropriate.

For use, either add a button in the Storyboard and link it to the class ButtonWithBadge and switch the badge on or off as required:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myButton: ButtonWithBadge!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(myButton)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    // if condition for showing badge with defaults ( size = 7, indents = 3):
    myButton.addBadge(withBadgeTag: 12345)
    
    // or alternatively create badge with size 10 and indents of 5
    myButton.addBadge(withBadgeTag: 12345, badgeSize: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10), indentTop: 5, indentRight: 5)
    
    // if condition is equal to no badge:
    myButton.removeBadge(withBadgeTag: 12345)
}
```

}

If you want to show a content (e.g. number) in the badge, just adjust the size and add the input as additional parameter in the function 'addBadge' and assign it to the label

Comment: This also works nice as extension on UIButton

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [pod](https://github.com/kiwisip/BadgeControl)

First clone the repo in your xcode
Then import the library in your file

1. add podfile to your project
2. add this line 'pod BadgeControl' to your podfile

your podfile will be like that

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'myProject' do
use_frameworks!
# Pods for myProject
pod 'BadgeControl'
end
```

Then close your Xcode project
Then pod install in your terminal

Then open myProject.xcworkspace instead of myProject.xcodeproj

Open storyboard add button , connect it to your viewcontroller file and give it a name
then import BadgeControl

```
import BadgeControl
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var badgeButton: UIButton!

private var upperLeftBadge: BadgeController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Add badge to button
    upperLeftBadge = BadgeController(for: badgeButton, in: .upperLeftCorner, badgeBackgroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9674351811, green: 0.2441418469, blue: 0.4023343325, alpha: 1) , badgeHeight: 20, badgeTextColor: UIColor.white, borderWidth: 3)

    upperLeftBadge.addOrReplaceCurrent(with: "123 or abc", animated: true)

    upperLeftBadge.animateOnlyWhenBadgeIsNotYetPresent = true
    upperLeftBadge.animation = BadgeAnimations.leftRight
}
}
```

You could change position of the badge 'upperLeftCorner' with lowerLeftCorner, upperRightCorner and lowerRightCorner

And you could change the animation 'leftRight' with rightLeft, fadeIn and rolling

And you  could change badgeBackgroundColor and badgeTextColor to any color you want

Also you could change badgeHeight

Change this line

```
upperLeftBadge.animateOnlyWhenBadgeIsNotYetPresent = false
```

if you want animation when badge is already present on the view.

Run your project.